# Syntax error in script for chacking date of file modification

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

So I wanted to make a script in shell that when executed, either modifies a file or echoes back a message.

Here is what I managed to write:

```
#!/bin/bash

current=$(date +%s)
last_modified='stat -c "Y" $/home/userr/textfile'

if
[ $((current-last_modified)) -gt 120 ]; then
        touch /home/userr/textfile;
else
        echo "File was modified less than 2 minutes ago";
fi
```

ShellCheck says everything is okay, but when I try to execute it it says:
`stat -c "Y" $/home/userr/textfile: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ""Y" $/home/userr/textfile")`

Any idea where I do go wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you mean "%Y"?

Comment: Thats exactly where I was wrong. Thank you alot for noticing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem might be this line:

```
last_modified='stat -c "Y" $/home/userr/textfile'
```

There you assign the string `stat -C "Y" ...` to the variable. What you might want to do instead is assigning the output of a command like `stat -c %Y /home/userr/textfile` which you could write as follows:

```
last_modified="$(stat -c %Y /home/userr/textfile)"
```

I recommend using `#!/bin/sh -e` for all shell scripts (you do not need bash here :) ) where `-e` enables fail-fast behaviour such that errors do not go undetected.

Comment: That's exactly where I was wrong. Thank you very much for noticing. But why didn't shellcheck tell me the error?

Comment: Shellcheck does not detect that error because the other thing is a perfectly valid shell script from a syntactical point of view :) Its static analysis does not detect that at runtime, the variable `last_modified` will be some text (`stat ...`) instead of a number as required for the `$((current - last_modified))` part.

Comment: Will have that in mind. Thank you alot. :)